# What Logic Shall i Adopt If i have a requirement to Read an office 365 email item and then respond on top of the same email chain

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

GraphAPI Requirements:

1. Read Email.
2. Reply to same email chain

Problem Statement:
I am not able to post a reply on top of the same email chain. When I do so, a new email is sent. But my requirement is to send a reply on top of the existing email chain.

#### Output is like:

> Hi Team,
>
> This Email has been sent from GraphAPI Code
>
> Thanks
>
> Abhijeet

#### Associated code:

```cs
-- -- -- Main Method-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("App started \n");
    ReadingEmail.AppClientCall();
}


-- -- -- ReadingEmail.cs Class file-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
class ReadingEmail {
    public static GraphServiceClient client;
    public static string _draftId = null;

    public static void AppClientCall() {
        client = GraphApiAuthenticationClient.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
        String email = "xyz@.onmicrosoft.com";
        var messages = client.Users[email].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Select(e => new {
            e.Subject,
            e.IsRead,
            e.Id
        }).GetAsync();

    if (messages.Result.Count == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("no messages in mailbox");
    }

    foreach(Message message in messages.Result) {
        if (message.Subject.Contains("190 Report") && message.IsRead == false) {
            Console.WriteLine("Found 190 Report named :" + message.Subject);
            message.IsRead = true;
            clsReplyAll.CreateReplyAll(message.Id); // Api Call too create draft                    
        }
            Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


-- -- -- clsReplyAll.cs class file-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -

class clsReplyAll
{
    public static GraphServiceClient client;

    public static async void CreateReplyAll(string p)
    {
        client = GraphApiAuthenticationClient.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
        String email = "xyz@.onmicrosoft.com";
        await client.Users[email].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages[p].CreateReplyAll().Request().PostAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Inbox Id: \n" + p);
        clsUpdateDraftedEmail.Update(p); // For api call to update Draft
    }
}


-- -- -- clsUpdateDraftedEmail.cs-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
class clsUpdateDraftedEmail {
    public static GraphServiceClient client;
    public static async void Update(string _inboxEmailid)
    {
        client = GraphApiAuthenticationClient.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
        String email = "xyz@.onmicrosoft.com";

        Message _msg = PrepareEmail();
        var did = await client.Users[email].MailFolders.Drafts.Messages.Request()
            .Select(e => new {e.Id}).GetAsync()
        ;
        var _getDraftFileID = did.CurrentPage.First().Id;
        Console.WriteLine("InboxId: \n" + _inboxEmailid + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Draft id: \n" + _getDraftFileID);

        CallGraphApiToUpdateTheDraftMessageWithBody(_getDraftFileID, _msg); // Call api to add body
    }

    private static Message PrepareEmail()
    {
        Message _msg = new Message {
            Body = new ItemBody {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = "Hi Team,<br> <br>This Email is send from GraphAPI Code </br> <br>Thanks</br> <br>Abhijeet</br>"
            },
            InferenceClassification = InferenceClassificationType.Other
        };
        return _msg;
    }

    private static async void CallGraphApiToUpdateTheDraftMessageWithBody(string _getDraftFileID, Microsoft.Graph.Message _msg)
    {
        client = GraphApiAuthenticationClient.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
        String email = "xyz@.onmicrosoft.com";
        await client.Users[email].MailFolders.Drafts.Messages[_getDraftFileID].Request().UpdateAsync(_msg);
        SendEmails.SendTheFileReply(_getDraftFileID);
    }
}


-- -- -- SendEmails.cs-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
class SendEmails {
    public static GraphServiceClient client;

    public static async void SendTheFileReply(string _getDraftFileID)
    {
        client = GraphApiAuthenticationClient.GetAuthenticatedClientForApp();
        String email = "xyz@.onmicrosoft.com";
        await client.Users[email].MailFolders.Drafts.Messages[_getDraftFileID].Send().Request().PostAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Mail Send");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a reply (with `CreateReplyAll`) but never use it! Your `PrepareEmail` function just creates a new message that isn't connected at all to the message you want to reply to.

You should get the `Message` object returned from `CreateReplyAll` and use that instead. Something like:

```
var reply = await client.Users[email]
    .MailFolders
    .Inbox
    .Messages[p]
    .CreateReplyAll()
    .Request().PostAsync();
```